# Does certain Fn key like F11 does not work for services which are linked to automator?

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, keybindings

So I did a small automator to toggle wifi on/off. I put that in services so I can assign a shortcut in keyboard in system preference.

I can assign F12, F10 all seems good but when I assign F11,  when I press F11 it does not do anything but give me a error sound... However assign F11 to other non-service like mission control totally works...

I'm using Apple Wireless Keyboard (latest) with my Macbook pro on Catalina

Is F11 special for certain programs or blocked for assignment?

Answer (score 1):

By default **F11** is assigned to **[√] Show Desktop** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Mission Control** and is why assigning it to an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** does not work.

You need to either pick a different *keyboard shortcut* or disable whatever is already using it. In this case, uncheck: **[]  **Show Desktop**** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Mission Control**.

[image]